# How to iterate each value in 2 different array in dart/flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, logic

please help about logic in dart,

i have 2 array:

```
option1 = ["green", "yellow", "purple"
option2 = [32,33]
```

and i want to iterate them into this:

```
mergedArray = [["green", 32], ["green", 33], ["yellow", 32], ["yellow",33], ["purple",32], ["purple",33]]
```

help will be greatly appreciated, thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two for loops for this. Loop through `option2` then inside it, loop through `option1`. Inside `option1`'s for loop you can add it to your list.

```
void main() {
  final List<String> option1 = ["green", "yellow", "purple"];
  final List<int> option2 = [32, 33];
  List<List<dynamic>> myList=[];
  for (var item2 in option2) {
    for (var item1 in option1) {
      myList.add([item1, item2]);
    }
  }
  print(myList);
}
```

Output:

```
[[green, 32], [yellow, 32], [purple, 32], [green, 33], [yellow, 33], [purple, 33]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void main(){
  
List<List> mergedArray=[]; 
  
List option1 = ["green", "yellow", "purple"];
List option2 = [32,33];
  
  for(int i =0;i<option1.length;i++){
    
    for(int j=0;j<option2.length;j++){
      mergedArray.add([option1[i],option2[j]]);
    }
  }
  
  mergedArray.forEach((val){
    print(val); //op:Your desired op
  });
}
```

Comment: you don't have to forEach mergedArray but this is a nice answer.

Comment: Yup just a cleaner one those who are unfamiliar with inbuilt function as such